# Как сделать va_start() и т.п. функции?

Tags: c, libc

Здравствуйте, я пишу себе свою маленькую libc, так вот хочу сделать printf для этого нужно va_* функции, код glibc я не понял совсем, там для меня все сложно, а в linux kernel 0.0.1 я увидел такой код:

```
typedef char *va_list;

#define __va_rounded_size(TYPE)  \
  (((sizeof (TYPE) + sizeof (int) - 1) / sizeof (int)) * sizeof (int))

#ifndef __sparc__
#define va_start(AP, LASTARG)                       \
 (AP = ((char *) &(LASTARG) + __va_rounded_size (LASTARG)))
#else
#define va_start(AP, LASTARG)                       \
 (__builtin_saveregs (),                        \
  AP = ((char *) &(LASTARG) + __va_rounded_size (LASTARG)))
#endif

void va_end (va_list);      /* Defined in gnulib */
#define va_end(AP)

#define va_arg(AP, TYPE)                        \
 (AP += __va_rounded_size (TYPE),                   \
  *((TYPE *) (AP - __va_rounded_size (TYPE))))
```

Посидел поломал мозги и тоже не понял нечего.
Может кто помочь найти простую реализацию функций `va_*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, `va_` это не функции и функциями быть не могут. Это макросы.

Во-вторых, нет никакой абстрактной универсальной "простой" реализации макросов `va_`. Реализация макросов `va_` должна быть точнехонько подогнана под действующее соглашение передачи параметров для вариадических (variadic) функций на данной платформе. Поэтому эти макросы - это всегда "хак", который подогнан под конкретный компилятор и, в общем случае, с другим компилятором работать не будет.

И я думаю, что проще, чем уже написанные макросы `va_` для вашего компилятора, вы ничего найти не сможете. Авторы этих реализаций не занимаются бессмысленными переусложнениями кода.

В том коде, который вы процитировали выше, ничего сложного нет. Он просто "ползет" по памяти указателем `char *AP` и вычитывает оттуда последовательные аргументы, размер которых округляется до `sizeof (int)`. Т.е. данный компилятор передает параметры вариадических функций именно так: выравнивает их размер до `sizeof(int)` и аккуратненько кладет их в стек один за другим.

Проще сделать не получится.